# How to scrape polygon from maps using request into a file that can be imported into google maps?

Tags: python, python-requests, geospatial

I have a web https://jakartasatu.jakarta.go.id/portal/apps/experiencebuilder/experience/?id=be77dd30a600425e9a76d11c6b6b0272&page=page_5

Where I want to get all the polygons value for the layer rencana detail tata ruang
I am currently stuck at converting the values scraped into something I can use in:

```
https://services6.arcgis.com/LpNjFysmsfdTpDD0/ArcGIS/rest/services/Rencana_Pola_Ruang_RDTR/FeatureServer/0/query?f=pbf&geometry=11892378.608714778%2C-688544.7507897057%2C11893601.60116734%2C-687321.7583371401&maxRecordCountFactor=4&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=8000&where=1%3D1&orderByFields=OBJECTID&outFields=*&quantizationParameters=%7B%22extent%22%3A%7B%22xmin%22%3A11892378.608714778%2C%22ymin%22%3A-688544.7507897057%2C%22xmax%22%3A11893601.60116734%2C%22ymax%22%3A-687321.7583371401%7D%2C%22mode%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22originPosition%22%3A%22upperLeft%22%2C%22tolerance%22%3A2.388657133911135%7D&resultType=tile&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&defaultSR=102100
```

in which the text for the polygon is generated.

Currently my code is

```
import requests
payload={
'geometry': 
'11889932.62380965,-688544.7507897057,11891155.616262212,-687321.7583371401',
'maxRecordCountFactor':'4',
'resultOffset': 
'0',
'resultRecordCount': 
'8000',
'where': 
'1=1',
'orderByFields': 
'OBJECTID',
'outFields': 
'*',
'quantizationParameters': 
{"extent":{"xmin":'11889932.62380965,"ymin":-688544.7507897057,"xmax":11891155.616262212,"ymax":-687321.7583371401'},"mode":"view","originPosition":"upperLeft","tolerance":'2.388657133911135'}
'resultType':'tile'
'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects'
'geometryType': 'esriGeometryEnvelope'
'defaultSR': '102100'
}
jsonmap=requests.get('https://services6.arcgis.com/LpNjFysmsfdTpDD0/ArcGIS/rest/services/Rencana_Pola_Ruang_RDTR/FeatureServer/0/query?f=pbf&geometry=11889932.62380965%2C-688544.7507897057%2C11891155.616262212%2C-687321.7583371401&maxRecordCountFactor=4&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=8000&where=1%3D1&orderByFields=OBJECTID&outFields=*&quantizationParameters=%7B%22extent%22%3A%7B%22xmin%22%3A11889932.62380965%2C%22ymin%22%3A-688544.7507897057%2C%22xmax%22%3A11891155.616262212%2C%22ymax%22%3A-687321.7583371401%7D%2C%22mode%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22originPosition%22%3A%22upperLeft%22%2C%22tolerance%22%3A2.388657133911135%7D&resultType=tile&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&defaultSR=102100', payload=payload)
```

I just can't figure out what I am looking at.
How do you translate the file above into json() or shapefile so that I can read the data?

Any help on scraping argcis map would be so much of a help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `f=pbf` with `f=json` in your query to get json response (see also the discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385674/converting-arcgis-esri-pbf-to-geojson)):

[image]